# VB.net WHERE Statement for MySQL

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

Good evening everyone. I ran into a problem that has me somewhat stumped. I am converting over to MySQL from Access and it seems that some of the Syntax is different for a MySQL Query. What I am doing is an operator selects a Client form a "ComboBox" which is populated from records in the "Client" table. I got that done with no problems. When the user selects a client, another combobox gets populated with data from the table "Lines". The table "Lines" has 2 columns Client and Line. I was trying to get each line WHERE Client = LEXAR. Any thoughts or ideas?

I figured it would be something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM Lines WHERE Client=LEXAR"

or

"SELECT * FROM Lines WHERE(client = @LEXAR)"

or

"SELECT * FROM Lines WHERE(client = '@LEXAR')"

or

"SELECT * FROM Lines WHERE client LIKE LEXAR)"

or



"SELECT * FROM ``Lines``WHERE ``Client``='LEXAR')"

or

"SELECT * FROM Lines WHERE Client ='LEXAR')"
```

but none work. Here is my code:

```
Dim sql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Lines WHERE(client = @LEXAR)", con)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

        Dim DataAdapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(sql)
        DataAdapter1.Fill(dt)


        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Line"
        End If
        con.Close()
```

These are the errors:

```
Fatal error encountered during command execution.
```

and

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Lines WHERE client =  LEXAR)' at line 1
```

Full Code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=productiontrackerpro;User ID=xxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxx;")


Public Sub LoadClients()

        Dim sql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Lines WHERE Client = 'LEXAR')", con)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

        Dim DataAdapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(sql)
        DataAdapter1.Fill(dt)


        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Line"
        End If
        con.Close()




    End Sub
```

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Lines WHERE Client = 'LEXAR')' at line 1
```

Comment: Not a MySQL guy, but try `SELECT * FROM Lines WHERE Client = 'LEXAR'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach was almost correct. Just place the term in single quotes:

```
"SELECT * FROM `Lines` WHERE `Client` = 'LEXAR';"
```

If you want to use parameters (WHERE somefield = @value) have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-prepared.html

Comment: ok, "lines" and "client" are MySQL commands. Use ```SELECT * FROM `Lines` WHERE `Client`='LEXAR'``` instead    (place the fields in single backticks)

Comment: Getting the same syntax error. I know it is probably something simple. I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Posted above dwtm.  Thanks.

Comment: Im don't know what it is. If I do it in PHP Select * From Lines Where Client LIKE '$client_name' it executes fine.

Comment: New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Lines WHERE Client = 'LEXAR')", con) if this is your current statement, **remove the closing bracket from the query** like so: ```New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `Lines` WHERE `Client` = 'LEXAR'", con)``` and use **only single** backticks, see my updated answer.

Comment: Ok. That worked. QUESTION: Why the semicolon(;), if you don't mind explaining. That threw me off a little bit.

Comment: If you only use 1 query, you don't really need the semicolon in .net. Since it's MySQLs default query delimiter, which I often use on command line, I always use it in .net as well. As soon as you write more than one query in your SQL, you must use it to delimit the queries. So for me, it's a "best practice" to always end my SQL-queries with a semicolon. For more info see: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2008/02/most-misunderstood-character-in-mysqls.html

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the help and the other link for more research.